# simple constructor causing error in qooxdoo - new qx.data.controller.Object();

Tags: qooxdoo

I'm getting errors when using basic qooxdoo objects. I am able to use some things just fine, but I am getting an error when I do:

```
var controller = new qx.data.controller.Object();
```

I get an error. In safari:

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'qx.data.controller' [undefined] is not an object.
```

In firefox:

```
qx.data.controller is undefined
```

Do you know why such a basic thing might be causing an error? I am running this code in main() in Application.js

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the class qx.data.controller.Object isn't included in your application. You need to run "generate.py source" whenever you use a new class in your code. Alternatively, you can run "generate.py source-all" once, which will include all known classes.

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought that I only had to regenerate source if I added new files/classes, not if I just referenced a new class. Thanks so much for the help!